# Generate mapping in Doctrine 2 from postgres DB

Tags: orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I'm generating xml files from Postgres DB using ORM from Doctrine. I have problem with composite primary key.

I have three tables for test: payment_plan, system_string, payment_plan_option.

Tables:

```
payment_plan:
   id                PK
   name_string_id    PK   FK  (system_string.id)


system_string:
   id                PK
   value         
   language_id   

payment_plan_option:
   id                PK
   payment_plan_id   PK     FK (payment_plan.id)
   price
```

When I generate XML for tables  *payment_plan* and *payment_plan_option* it's all OK.

When I generate for tables *payment_plan* and *system_string* I got error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                             
Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity Api\Entity\PaymentPlan
```

I've tried add some field to payment_plan so it's look like payment_plan_option but with no effects.

Comment: I can't tell unless you show us some generated entities  but  I ran into a case when generating entities from exiting database : https://gist.github.com/4079388 , you may try it , its a good start :)

Comment: Provide your entities your question is incomplete